# I have this file in matlab, how do I open it with pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, matlab

I have this file https://mega.nz/file/9tMlnALK#usFDanDAD6qp6TTZU9bFEoP6FPmeNPhMAa75Q5jgE7w, which is coded in .mat, inside there're many variables. I have a code that works with pandas datframe, so I need to access one variable (a matrix called F ideally I want to access some indexes of the matrix not the entire matrix) in order to use the code with it.

I was trying to use loadmat but as I said i dont know how to access just the matrix and not the other dat. How I may do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have try the below code:

[Convert mat](https://gist.github.com/iaalm/fc4133707a33c99c693408c304d426bd)

Comment: Could you please post the code? On Stack Overflow posters are encouraged to [provide context for links and quote most relevant parts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).